# Deploying a Workflow Causes Issue With Adding a New Item To a List

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a list that has a workflow called Testing WF deployed to it shown below as proof:

[image]

I add a new item to my list called Test7 below. The issue is that it gets stuck on “**Sending data to the server…**”

[image]

After a few minutes of waiting I see the below error message:

[image]

When I click on **Close**, the item gets added anyways:

[image]

I check on the workflow status shown below:

[image]

When I check, I get the message below that says that there are no running workflows:

[image]

I have tested and created another list with just an InfoPath form and **DID NOT** deploy a workflow and everything works fine.

Why is publishing a workflow causing issues with the list?